# How large is a "buffer" in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, performance

I am using `pg_buffercache` module for finding hogs eating up my RAM cache. For example when I run this query:

```
SELECT c.relname, count(*) AS buffers
FROM pg_buffercache b INNER JOIN pg_class c
    ON b.relfilenode = c.relfilenode AND
       b.reldatabase IN (0, (SELECT oid FROM pg_database WHERE datname = current_database()))
GROUP BY c.relname
ORDER BY 2 DESC
LIMIT 10;
```

I discover that `sample_table` is using 120 buffers.

How much is 120 buffers in bytes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PostgreSQL has a hard coded block size of **8192** bytes -- see the [pre-defined block_size variable](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/runtime-config-preset.html).  This used to be a number to hold in mind whenever you edited the config to specify `shared_buffers`, etc., but the config now supports suffixes like `MB` which will do the conversion for you.

It is possible, with hard work, to change block_size to other values.  For a minority of applications there might be a more optimal size, but the number of places the code makes an assumption about the size is large.

Comment: Thank you. Does shared_buffers = 2 GB mean I have 2*2^10^3/8192 = 262144 buffers?

Comment: Yup!  This may of course lead to performance issues when running pg_buffer_cache, since it's so many.  But that's a small price to pay if 2GB is the best cache size for your PG cluster.

Answer (score 0):

According to what Edmund said, we can make this select in our scheme database:

```
SELECT c.relname,
   Pg_size_pretty(Count(*) * 8192)
   AS buffered,
   Round(100.0 * Count(*) / (SELECT setting
                             FROM   pg_settings
                             WHERE  name = 'shared_buffers') :: INTEGER, 1)
   AS
   buffers_percent,
   Round(100.0 * Count(*) * 8192 / Pg_relation_size(c.oid), 1)
   AS
   percent_of_relation
FROM   pg_class c
       INNER JOIN pg_buffercache b
               ON b.relfilenode = c.relfilenode
       INNER JOIN pg_database d
               ON ( b.reldatabase = d.oid
                    AND d.datname = Current_database() )
WHERE  Pg_relation_size(c.oid) > 0
GROUP  BY c.oid,
          c.relname
ORDER  BY 3 DESC
LIMIT  10;
```