# Reading pg_buffercache output

Tags: postgresql

I am using postgres-9.3 (in CenOS 6.9) and trying to understand the pg_buffercache table output.

I ran this:

```
SELECT c.relname,count(*) AS buffers FROM pg_class c INNER JOIN 
pg_buffercache b ON b.relfilenode=c.relfilenode INNER JOIN 
pg_database d ON (b.reldatabase=d.oid AND 
d.datname=current_database()) GROUP BY c.relname
ORDER BY 2 DESC LIMIT 5;
```

and the output below showed one of the tables using 6594 buffers. This was during when I had tons of INSERT followed by SELECT and UPDATE in the data_main table).

```
       relname      | buffers 
  ------------------+---------
  data_main         |    6594
  objt_main         |    1897
  objt_access       |     788
  idx_data_mai      |     736
```

I also ran "select * from pg_buffercache where is dirty" which showed around 50 entries.

How should I interpret these numbers? Does the buffer count correspond to all the transactions since I created the extension or the recent ones. How can I find out if my specific operation using the proper amount of buffers?

Here's my setting:

```
 # show shared_buffers;
    shared_buffers 
  ----------------
     1GB

 # show work_mem;
  work_mem
 ----------
   128kB
 # show maintenance_work_mem;
   maintenance_work_mem 
  ----------------------
   64GB
```

And the current free mem (I have 64GM memory in this machine). And I have a mixed workload machine with period bursts of INSERTS and lots of SELECTS. Currently the database and tables are small but will grow to at least 2 million rows.

```
  $ free -m
         total       used      free     shared    buffers     cached
 Mem:   64375      33483      30891        954         15      15731
 /+ buffers/cache: 18097      46278
Swap:   32767         38      32729
```

Basically, I am trying to understand how to properly use this pg_buffercache table. Should I ran this query periodically? And do I need to change my shared_buffers accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

I did some reading and testing and this is what I have found. Found a userful query here: [How large is a "buffer" in PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2887402/how-large-is-a-buffer-in-postgresql/40678099#40678099)

Here are a few notes for others that have similar questions.

1. You will need to create the extension for each database. So "\c db_name" then "create extension pg_buffercache".
2. Same for running the queries.
3. Restarting the database clears the queries.